# Handling multiple constraint violations at once

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

I have a situation where I have to return constraint violations for multiple fields to the Client in a single response.

Currently I'm letting the database fail and then return the appropriate `error_code` to the Client, it worked fine until the requirement for validating all fields at once.
Of course this is because of the nature of exception handling, the first index violation sql stumbles upon will throw an exception, it'll be returned and that's it.

What I could think about is performing some custom fluent validation on each field for uniqueness, but I am aware this is not the best solution because of the possible race condition, where one record could be inserted "in the meantime" between the check and an insert.

What is the best strategy for handling these situations?

Comment: check and return the errors, you need to show what you have tried what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like a task for the application layer. Though SQL Server should have `CHECK` `CONSTRAINTS` on the data, the application layer should also be making sure it does checks on the validity of the data; which can be far more interactive and informative (and in scenarios, be much better, such as with validation of string formatting).

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that as well, for string formatting and stuff like that that is totally valid, I'm more concerned with the validations that check for uniqueness for instance and what if another insert happens between the previous check and insert, somehow it seems to me that it's much more error-prone to perform these kind of checks in the application layer. But right at the moment, I'm thinking that I could live with the possibility of an edge case like that to occurr.

Comment: The constraints should be the last line of defence. You can check within your procedure that the values match the constraints using `EXISTS` clauses, and then return custom error codes

Comment: You'll end up needing to deal with the constraint error anyway, lest you miss the race condition where you check the constraint, then someone else adds data that will cause a conflict, then you attempt your modification. And it's expensive to do the work again in the application layer - you're at least doubling the work that the DB will do, because it has to check now, and check again later when you attempt the modification. Not so bad to let the DB handle, IMO.

Comment: Yes but If I leave it to the DB then I have a problem where DB will terminate data modification and return after the first constraint violation occurs, but I need to batch all the violations and return them in a single response.

If I do the checks for the data uniqueness before it attempts insert/update and return validation result I won't have to deal with the constraint error.

Comment: If you do all of the validation in a stored procedure (SP) in the database then you can start a transaction, perform the validation one step at a time while assembling the status of each check, then perform the operation or not, end the transaction appropriately and return the accumulated status information. Unfortunately you'll have to implement the constraint checks individually in your own code so that you can handle each result independently. You can also deny direct access to the underlying table so that users can only use your SP(s) to make changes.

Comment: Hey there,

My take on this would be to do as suggested by @HABO:
 1. have a SP to handle the DB request
 2. have each check in a separated try/catch block
 3. add each error message on the catch to a list/table
 4. return the error list/table
 5. You can add an unique index/constraint for the data that is to have uniqueness check

Comment: I am aware that this approach has a lot of issues, specially if you send a list of data rows to be inserted:
 1. You would need to loop for each row and try/catch a single insertion. This brings performance and complexity
 2. Even when trying to add just one row, more than one issue can occur and you would only get the first exception. SQL Server breaks at the first one.